# '_io.TextIOWrapper' no attribute 'replace'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm pretty new to Python. I'm trying to learn how to create modules and import functions, so the reason this is in two files is because I'm fooling around with that. It seems to me that that's not the problem though, but I figured I'd put some backstory in there in case it was relevant.

I know my formatting and variable/file/module naming are sloppy, this was supposed to be a quick once off little doozy, but I got stuck and now I'm obsessed.

Basically I just want to create a find and replace function for a file, but I keep running into this no matter how I format the file.replace(x , x) function.

## FILE 1 - FILEREAD.PY - Functions/Modules to read file

```
#!/user/bin/env python3
def readfile(filename):

    '''
    Function to open a file, format it and read it into
    a variable called filename
    '''

    fobj = open(filename)
    for line in fobj:
        print(line.rstrip())
    return filename
    return fobj
    fobj.close()

def readnewfile(filename, torep, withrep):

    '''
    Function to replace strings in file - NOT USED
    '''

    fobj = open(filename)
    for line in fobj:
        print(line.strip('\n'))
        print (fobj.replace(torep, withrep))
    return filename
    fobj.close()
```

## FILE 2 - REPLACE.PY - Asks for input and replaces data

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import string
from fileread import *

filename = input ('what is the path to the file you want to read: ')
readfile(filename)
print ('Read file ', filename) 
torep = input ('What word would you lke to replace: ')
withrep = input ('What word would you lie to replace it with: ')

print ('''





''')

#readnewfile(filename, torep, withrep)

#with open(filename) as temp:
change = open(filename).replace(torep, withrep)
print(change)
```

Comment: Sorry this is the full error: 

**AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'**

Comment: you can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31214938/edit) your question to add the full traceback

Comment: Last time I edited my question a mod took it out and referred me to the rules saying I should leave it in a comment or put it in an answer. Unless the rules for stack overflow are different from those of codereview.stackexchange.

Seems the community thought either this question, or my behavior was stupid, as I'm being told I might be blocked entirely for it... Bummer. Wish I knew specifics.

Comment: Code Review definitely has different rules. Would be happy to discuss in the Code Review chat room [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) (and yes, it can be confusing).

Comment: @ChrisGleason As long as you don't *invalidate existing answers*, you'll be alright! (Code Review has to deal with answer invalidation quite a lot). It can be a bit confusing at the beginning, but after a while I'm sure you will learn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exception is coming from the line:

```
change = open(filename).replace(torep, withrep)
```

You're calling a `replace` method that does not exist on a file object (which is returned from `open`). I suspect you want to be calling the `replace` method that strings have. Try:

```
change = open(filename).read().replace(torep, withrep)
```

This calls `read()` to read in the file's contents as a single string, then calls `replace` on that string.

It might be a good idea to split up the operation over several lines, but I've kept it in the same structure you currently have. There are a number of other things that could be improved in your code (e.g. using `with` as you've started to do), but I think the issue above is the one that has you stuck at the moment.

Comment: Nice. That worked.   <br/>
So if I was to structure it using the _with_ I would just format it like:  <br/>
`with open(filename) as temp:`
`    change = temp.read().replace(torep, withrep)`
`print(change)`

Comment: Sorry don't know how to edit comments yet! Was in the middle of formattint when it told me I surpassed the 5 minute mark!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% on how to format comments yet, and the rules say I can answer my own question with a solution, however I want to credit  @Blckknght for giving it.

I just replaced it by calling read() and it works fine now:

```
with open(filename) as temp:
    change = temp.read().replace(torep, withrep)
print(change)
```